# MySQL gives incorrect DateTime Value for some dates but not others

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this in MySQL:

```
mysql> describe sale;
+-------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id          | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| timestamp   | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| salesperson | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| customer    | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| product     | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| count       | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Now if a run this statement, I get an ERROR 1292:

```
mysql> insert into `sale` values (25860,'2006-04-02 02:30:50',1,25,2,21);
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2006-04-02 02:30:50' for column 'timestamp' at row 1
```

However, if I just change the date by one day, the statement works:

```
mysql> insert into `sale` values (25860,'2006-04-03 02:30:50',1,25,2,21);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

What is the magical thing about the second of April 2006? I can't detect any problems with the format specified. I also tried retyping the statement to make sure it was not caused by invisible characters.

Comment: Daylight savings time.

Comment: This doesn't give me an error on mine. I tested on MySQL version: '10.1.13-MariaDB'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daylight Saving Time.

On `2006-04-02` at 2am the clock jumped to 3am. So there was no `02:30:50`
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have removed all dates that are in the daylight saving span and it now seem to be working!